# textual questionnaire system - swift 3

Tags: swift, text

This question is about building a textual questionnaire system using swift 3.
Assuming we have (n) questions, the user will be asked one question at the time, replying with text (using UITextField).
if the answer is something that is expected (YES/NO for example) the code will carry on to the next question, otherwise it will try to give some more elaborate question with possible answers (see code below).

*The idea is having some kind of an array of dictionaries, each dictionary (questionItem) contains a single question/answer data...*

**Question:** even if the following code works fine, I feel that this is not the most scalable nor elegant solution. Thus my question is more about your ideas regarding code design.
**how can one make a code such as this - that is scalable for multiple questions.**

```
static var questionItem = [
    "question": "Is the sky blue?",
    "answer": "yes",
    "afterAnswer": "question #2",
    "explanation": "simply answer: yes or no"
]



class func getAnswer(answer: String) -> String
{
    let expectedAnswer = questionItem["answer"]
    let isEqual = (answer == expectedAnswer)

    var respond = "undifined"

    if isEqual {
        // go for next question  ( questionItem["afterAnswer"] )
        respond = "ok, going to the next question"
    } else {
        // didn't got the answer I was waiting for, going to show some longer explanation
        respond = questionItem["explanation"]!

    }
   // respond
    return respond
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a struct with your desired information, then create a Trivia of Type Int: YourStruct to manage all the different questions answers and explanations, like my example below, let me know is its clear enough:

```
struct  QuestionsAndAnswers{

    var question: String = ""
    var answer: String = ""
    var explanation: String = ""

}

var trivia: [Int: QuestionsAndAnswers] = [:]

trivia = [1: QuestionsAndAnswers.init(question: "Your First Question", answer: "Your Fist Answer", explanation: "Your First explanation")]

trivia = [2: QuestionsAndAnswers.init(question: "Your Second Question", answer: "Your Second Answer", explanation: "Your Second explanation")]

func getAnswer(answer: String, quesiontNumber: Int) -> String
{
    let expectedAnswer = trivia[quesiontNumber]?.answer
    let isEqual = (answer == expectedAnswer)

    var respond = "undifined"

    if isEqual {
        // go for next question  ( questionItem["afterAnswer"] )
        respond = "ok, going to the next question"
    } else {
        // didn't got the answer I was waiting for, going to show some longer explanation
        respond = (trivia[quesiontNumber]?.explanation)!

    }
    // respond
    return respond
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nago, still your code is retuning an error : Expected declaration on the line below : var trivia: [Int: QuestionsAndAnswers] = [:]

Comment: are you using swift 3? I try it on playground and don't have any problem!

Comment: And have you declared the struct QuestionsAndAnswers? [link of image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24078452/Screen%20Shot%202016-10-17%20at%209.20.50%20AM.png) On this Link you can see an image of the code with no error.